# How to change image src depending on whether image exists

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, src

I'm trying to load one of two different thumbnail images according to whether or not an image corresponding to a database entry and identified with an id as part of its name exists on the system.

Simplifying a bit for clarity, if the specific image, named {id}-thumb.png, exists then I want to load its name into the src of the HTML using jQuery. If the image does not exist I want to load a generic thumbnail image named thumbnail.png.

This is what I have so far:

```
var image_path = id + "-thumb.png";
$.ajax({
    url: image_path,
    type: "HEAD",
    error: function() {
        $("li#" + id + " .thumbnail").attr("src","thumbnail.png");
    },
    success: function() {
        $("li#" + id + " .thumbnail").attr("src",id + "-thumb.png");
    }
});
```

Then I generate the new HTML to insert by building up a string variable, list_item

```
var list_item = "<li id='" + id + "'>";
list_item += "<figure>";
list_item += "<img class='thumbnail' src=''></a>";
list_item += "</figure>";
```

And finally I add this new list_item variable to the existing ul:

```
$(".list ul").prepend(list_item);
```

But I get no image and looking at the generated HTML, src is empty.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: You are not closing `li` .. `</li>`

Comment: your create dynamically your image name `attr("src",id + "-thumb.png");` but u are sure this is also the path to the image on disk. Check to see exactly your image path and add it to src attr

Comment: Is it just me or you're sending an ajax request to the picture?

Comment: your using ajax I think you can solve the problem on server side, which should much more easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the image does not exist you can use the "onerror" parameter. Generate the image tag like this:

```
<img src="something.jpg" onerror="this.src='something_else.jpg'" />
```

Comment: That just puts the text "something_else.jpg" on the page - not the image itself.

Comment: That works fine for me - excellent simple solution - many thanks.

Comment: Superb. Sorted my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Load generic thumb by default, then load specific one - if it does not exist, it won't get loaded:

```
<img src="path/to/generic_thumb.png" data-src="path/to/specific_thumb.png" alt="">
```

**JS**

```
$('img[data-src]').each(function(){

    var $self = $(this), specificSrc = $self.data('data-src');

    // create an img node, inject the real src attribute...
    $("<img />").bind("load", function() {

      // ...when it gets loaded [and the resource is thus available],
      // set it to the actual DOM img element.
      $self.attr('src', specificSrc);

    }).attr("src", specificSrc);

});
```